# Firebase UI recycler view adapter onDataChanged get reference to the data that changed

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

Im using firebase ui recyclerview adapter, as I understand it, when the acivity starts onDataChanged is called and then for every subsequent change in the database it is called again, what I want to do is check every child the first time onDataChanged is called and then only check the child that changed the next time it is called, so I was thinking I could set a boolean to tell the system if its the first time or not, but how can I after that only check the child that changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what the `onChildChanged` method is for.  It'll do exactly what you want:

```
@Override
public void onChildChanged(@NonNull ChangeEventType type,
                           @NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot,
                           int newIndex,
                           int oldIndex) {
    super.onChildChanged(type, snapshot, newIndex, oldIndex);
    MyData data = getItem(newIndex);
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks for this from the man himself supercilex, since i knew the adapter was using the childchanged event listener for some reason i thought this was listening to the children of those children